# Передача JSON-объекта из Jquery в PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Код jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var object1;
$(document).on("click",".button1",function(){
            object1={"key1":"123"}
            $.ajax({
                url:'ajax.php',
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"json",
                data:"param2="+JSON.stringify(object1),
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#addword').html(response);

                }
            })
});
});
```

Код ajax.php:

```
<?php include 'trainingmassiv.php';
if($_POST["param2"]){
echo json_encode($_POST["param2"]);
      }

?>
```

Имеется `span` с `id = "addword"`, куда записывается результат.

При нажатии на кнопку создаётся объект jquery и с помощью ajax-запроса отправляю объект Jquery в php, а затем обратно в jquery.

Объект записываю в переменную `param2`, затем обращаюсь к ней в PHP через `$_POST`.

Если передать в jquery только сам объект, то он печатается в виде: `{"key1":"123"}`, но если я хочу передать Jquery значение `"123"` ключа `key1`, то прописываю вместо:

`echo json_encode($_POST["param2"])`

это:

`echo json_encode($_POST["param2"]->key1)`,

и потом JSON возвращает `null`.

В чем может быть ошибка? В обратном слэше? Пытался убрать их из JSON-строки с помощью `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, но тогда вообще ничего не возвращается.

Answer (score 0):

там явно не скобках проблема... `data` не нужно форматировать в JSON-строку, $.ajax() сделает это сам, так же, как и респонс не нужно форматировать в объект

```
object1={"key1":"123"};
$.ajax({
    url:'ajax.php',
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{
        param2:object1
    },
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.key1);

    }
});
```

но скорей всего проблема в PHP. `$_POST` - массив, в этом случае, многомерный, и чтоб получить доступ к определенному ключу, нужно

```
if(isset($_POST['param2'])){
    if(isset($_POST['param2']['key1'])){
        echo json_encode(array('key1'=>$_POST['param2']['key1']));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('key1'=>$_POST['param2']));
    }
}
```

сделать это так

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ, сделал всё как написали, но консоль вывела следующее: {key1: null}
                      null. Значит он всё-таки нашёл ключ у объекта, но почему-то не вывел ни объект, ни ключ

Comment: @Ezhik, а PHP это весь? перед или после `echo json_encode($_POST)` ничего не выводится?

Comment: Я и сам не понял как, но он мне вывел что я хотел, сейчас скину код

Comment: ajax.php оставил таким: <?php include 'trainingmassiv.php'; if(isset($_POST['param2'])){echo json_encode(array('key1'=>$_POST['param2']));}
?>   А jquery изменил так: success:function(response){
                                     console.log(response.key1);
                                     console.log(response.key1.key1);
                                            $('#addword').html(response.key1.key1); И дальше консоль вывела: {key1: "123"}
               123

Comment: Теперь осталось только понять как это работает xD

Comment: странно все это... _осталось только понять как это работает_ - в консоле в соседней вкладке `Network` - можно отслеживать все запросы (заголовки, ответы, тайминги), без нее никуда)

Comment: Получается в этой строчке echo json_encode(array('key1'=>$_POST['param2'])); мы создаём массив, и в его индекс 'key1' записываем объект с ключом 'key1'?

Comment: да, но массив, как тут, создавать не обязательно. `$_POST` - уже массив, и `echo json_encode($_POST)` выведет все имеющиеся ключи и значения. К примеру в респонс прийдет строка `{"params2":{"key1":"123"}}` - обратится к `key1` можно будет `response.params2.key1`

Comment: Ещё один вопрос, нужно ли в PHP делать декодирование json_decode($_POST['param2']), чтобы потом присвоить декодированное значение какой-нибудь переменной и работать с ней? И только потом делать кодирование в JSON?

Comment: нет. по-сути, как сейчас, `$.ajax()` конвертировал объект `data` в понятный серверу формат (допустим отправляемый запрос имел вид `params[ke1]=123`), который был распарсен с помощью модуля apache `mod_php`, и которым была заполнена переменная `$_POST` до того, как стартовало выполнение скрипта `ajax.php`. Если оправить аяксом `data:{ param2: "{\"key1\":\"123\"}"}`, то надо будет декодировать `json_decode($_POST['param2'])` так как в `param2` отправилась JSON-строка

Comment: То есть ajax сам кодирует в json при отправке из jquery и сам декодирует его в код php, но не кодирует его сам при обратной отправке в jquery, но при этом сам декодирует его при принятии jquery

Comment: ну можно и так сказать. а вообще: jQuery отправил что-то, php - обработал это и хорошо. вся детальная инфа находится в консоле во вкладке `Сеть`. еще можно почитать про типы данных в PHP https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.php в особенности массивы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php и объекты https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.object.php

Comment: Можешь дать свой ВК? Обещаю часто не мучать

Comment: не, у меня ВК заблокирован) если что, то не стесняйся создавать темы на этом сайте, тут люди отзывчивые, всегда рады и готовы помочь

Comment: Ну в общем такая проблема, путем тестирования выяснилось, что если значение ключа - строка, то консоль молчит :)

Comment: У меня уже голова болит, решаешь одну проблему, думаешь что решил, а потом вылезает другая

Comment: а в каком смысле **значение ключа - строка** ? если это ответ выглядит так `{"какой-то ключ":"какое-то значение"}`, то обращаться к ней надо `response["какой-то ключ"]`. тест: `let object = {
   ["что-то"]:"кое как"
  };
  console.log(object["что-то"]);`

Comment: Ну то есть у меня значение ключа было 123,но если написать abcd, то ничего не выводится

Comment: а в консоле во вкладке `Сеть` какой ответ приходит?

Comment: Извиняюсь, оно оказывается работает, я просто раскомментировал обращение к базе данных, а в запросе видимо ошибка, поэтому код до этой строчки не доходил, буду теперь искать ошибку в запросе )